# Select N to N rows from database using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table with 30 rows, i want to fetch rows from 15-25 using LINQ, tried using Range operator but that is not working in my scenario.

any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your scenario exactly and why didn't range work for you? It would be hard to help you without some more information on your problem

Comment: Would `<linq query>.Skip(15).Take(11)` work?

Comment: yes, this works like a charm.. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<your linq>.Skip(n).Take(m)`, which will take the values between n and m.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882968%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882788%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for that:

```
var result = query.Skip(14).Take(11);
```

<del>(But I'm not 100% sure your query provider can translate that correctly to sql).</del>

Comment: I've never seen a linq provider that didn't support those operators, they translate well to SQL.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I just wasn't sure because I rarerly have the opportunity to use linq to sql. And I remember answering questions with linq methods that weren't supported. So I'm just careful.